# XSAVE causes Unhandled exception in VS 2017

Tags: assembly, x86

This code is being run on an Intel 4770K (which supports AVX2 and XSAVE set). The environment is MASM (in VS 2017).

```
and  rsp,-40H     ; aligns stack to 64 byte
sub  rsp,2000H    ; creates enough space to write out the XSAVE
mov  qword ptr xsave_space_ptr, rsp
xor  rcx,rcx      ; XCR(0)
xgetbv            ; returns RAX:7,RDX:0
mov  rax,7
mov  rdx,0
xsave  qword ptr xsave_space_ptr ; this is where the VS 2017 crashes.
```

Any suggestion on what is incorrect in this usage is welcome. It also fails if all bits in the EDX:EAX are set to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
xsave  qword ptr xsave_space_ptr
```

It is irrelevant what value is contained in `xsave_space_ptr`, the location you're `xsave`ing to here is `xsave_space_ptr` itself. `xsave` (like any typical instruction that writes to memory) writes to the address it is given, it doesn't read a pointer from the address it is given and then write to wherever the pointer points, which this code seems to assume. Therefore the address it writes to here may not be 64-aligned (why would it be, except by coincidence) which would cause an exception. It looks like you intended to do this:

```
xsave [rsp]
```

Comment: I didnt quite follow why u are assuming that it reads the pointer from XSAVE location and then writes to that pointer address - not certain why u gathered that impression. And yes, it simply does xsave [rsp] but XSAVE requires a _mem_ dest operand, not _reg_ dest operand. The var xsave_save_reg is just the forced 64 byte aligned value of RSP

Comment: @quasar66 because you're storing some pointer in memory and then giving `xsave` the address of the pointer. But `xsave` doesn't work like that (nothing does, as far as I know), it just writes directly to whatever address you give it - which is `xsave_space_ptr`, not the address saved there. So, in order to do `xsave [rsp]`, you just write `xsave [rsp]`, `[rsp]` is a "mem operand" so that's fine.